# Objeto global para projeto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com dúvida, se este modo seria um método muito "feio" de se fazer:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6df36cc016a10bed0d66

No caso, foi definido um objeto chamado "Ecommerce", e estou atribuindo a ele as funcionalidades.

Outro item que gostaria de saber outras formas, ou se está correto, é o carregamento de plugins no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Helder, esse código é bem grande. Eu quero ajudar mas não vou olhar para esse código todo, não tenho tempo. Dá para clarificar a pergunta e juntar um esquema do código?

Comment: Minha dúvida é se, definir este objeto "Ecommerce" e atribuir todas as funcionalidades a ele é correto de se fazer.

O outro item é referente aos plugins que são carregados no fim do arquivo, seria melhor criar um "plugins.js" por exemplo, ao invés de carrega-los no mesmo arquivo? Em questão de performance, seria melhor 1 arquivo só né, pois é uma requisição a menos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criar um objeto com todos os métodos que precisa é muito boa ideia. É o que se chama criar um *name space*. Assim evita conflitos no caso de declarar variáveis ou funções com nomes que possam já existir.

Em relação a juntar vários códigos no mesmo ficheiro depende um pouco. Se o script total não fôr muito grande é bom ter no mesmo ficheiro para ter tudo organizado.
Se fôr grande pode ser melhor do ponto de vista de performance ter vários pedidos paralelos a correr em simultaneo, isso faz a página carregar mais rápido apesar de serem vários pedidos.

O código que não precise de estar na `<head>` (código que não é preciso antes do utilizador interagir) pode carregar depois (fora do head) e assim faz também a página carregar mais rápido.